# Why I got error in this tr-catch-finally block?

Tags: python

If python codes like this, no error report:

```
try:
    sock=socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(20)
    sock.connect(sock_name)
    test_vm_connectivity(sock)
except Exception as e:
    process_output(e)
finally:
    sock.settimeout(None)
    sock.close()
```

If python codes like this, got errors, I don't know why:

```
for sock_name in vm_socks:
    try:
        sock=socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(20)
        sock.connect(sock_name)
        test_vm_connectivity(sock)
    except Exception as e:
        process_output(e)
    finally:
        sock.settimeout(None)
        sock.close()
```

Error:

```
[root@yf-mos-test-net09 tests]# python run-vhost
global name 'socket' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run-vhost", line 237, in <module>
    test_all()
  File "run-vhost", line 215, in test_all
    sock.settimeout(None)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sock' referenced before assignment
```

I don't know what's different in the two codes. For code2, how to correct it, please help, thank you~

Comment: In code 2, you are iterating through different values of `sock_name`, and one of those causes the crash.

Comment: if `socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM)` fials, then `sock` is not assigned, and `sock.settimeout(None)` in `finally` results in your error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem actually exists (potentially at least) in your first snippet too but you haven't stumble upon it before.

The source of the problem is that the `socket()` call can raise an exception. If this happens and it's the first iteration, the name `sock` will not be defined, then you end up in the `finally` clause where you do reference this not-yet-existant name.

The Q&D solution is mostly to make sure `sock` is defined before the try/except block:

```
for sock_name in vm_socks:
    sock = None
    try:
        sock=socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(20)
        sock.connect(sock_name)
        test_vm_connectivity(sock)
    except Exception as e:
        process_output(e)
    finally:
        if sock:
            sock.settimeout(None)
            sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably place the socket creation outside the try-except-finally block or you will access the `sock` in the finally block even if its creation failed and it is not assigned.

```
for sock_name in vm_socks:
    sock=socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.settimeout(20)
        sock.connect(sock_name)
        test_vm_connectivity(sock)
    except Exception as e:
        process_output(e)
    finally:
        sock.settimeout(None)
        sock.close()
```

Comment: The diagnostic is good but the solution is not iso wrt/ the OP's code as `process_output(e)`  won't be called if an exception happens during the `socket()` call.

Comment: I think the socket creation is what causes the exception, so a (generally)  better alternative would be to assign `sock` to `None` before the `try` block, and try to create it inside of the `try` block.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access a variable that hasn't been declared is my understanding. To fix it, declare the variable before the "for" statement. I have not tested this but it should work.

Ex.

```
sock = "" #Declares a string without any data in the variable.
```